# C program returning 0 instead of max occurring integer from sequence of integer input

Tags: c, arrays, loops, printf, user-input

I posted earlier about a runtime error in my C program but now I'm having another issue with the code. My program runs fine without any errors but it always prints 0 no matter what the input. I've spent the last 4 hours trying to figure out why my code is doing that but I've had no luck. I would really appreciate if someone could give me a hand.

My program takes in an input of a sequence of integers, using another program that works like scanf. *Getint()* reads an input of a sequence of integers and stops reading the input when it reaches EOF (-1). The number of integers in the sequence is 1000.

```
// ar_max(a[]) returns the max entry of a
int ar_max(int a[]) {
  int max_so_far = a[0];
  for (int i = 1; i < 1000; i++) {
    if (a[i] > max_so_far) {
      max_so_far = a[i];
    }
  }
  return max_so_far;
}

int main() {
  int inputnum = getint();
  // array containing the distinct numbers seen
  int a_num[1000] = {};
  // array containing the frequencies of the distinct numbers seen
  int a_freq[1000] = {};
  int len_n = 0;
  while (inputnum != EOF) {
    int i = 0;
    len_n = i + 1;
    int len_f = len_n;
    // update the frequency of inputnum if it's already been seen
    for (i = 0; i < len_f; i++, len_n += 1) {
      if (a_num[i] == inputnum) {
        a_freq[i] = a_freq[i] + 1;
      }
    }
    // add inputnum into the array if it hasn't already been seen
    if (i == len_n) {
      a_num[i+1] = inputnum;
      a_freq[i+1] = 1;
    }
    inputnum = getint();
  }
  // print the first number with the highest frequency
  for (int j = 0; j < len_n; j++) {
    if (a_freq[j] == ar_max(a_freq)) {
      printf("%d\n", a_num[j]);
      break;
    }
  }
}
```

For example, an input of
`10 20 30 20`
should result in `20`

Comment: Try running in a debugger and step through the code line by line. Doing it form the normal input set is a little to time-consuming, so use a smaller input set for debugging.

Comment: please post complete code so we can reproduce your error.  We do not know what the function getint() does

Comment: I am only provided with the interface of getint() and not the implementation

Comment: I don't know how to run it in a debugger

Comment: can you at least show the prototype of getint ?

Comment: // getint() returns an int corresponding to the decimal digits which appear
//   in typed input
int getint(void);

If i write **int n = getint();** then n will be the first integer input and when i call **int n = getint();** again, n becomes the next integer input

Comment: learn how to debug first. There are tons of tutorials on google. And put code inside backticks (the same key with ~) `like this` to make it readable

Comment: 'I don't know how to run it in a debugger', OK, I don't know how to not downvote your question.  It seems like you are absolutely intent on doing no work yourself at all.

Answer (score 1):

The code has the right idea, but it still has some problems.

First, you have two arrays with related information. You keep two lengths for each of these arrays and try to keep the lengths the same. That's complicated. Instead, consider having just one length for both arrays.

When you loop thorugh the array in oder to check whether the given number is already contained in the array:

```
for (i = 0; i < len_f; i++, len_n += 1) {
  if (a_num[i] == inputnum) {
    a_freq[i] = a_freq[i] + 1;
  }
}
```

you update then length of the number array with each iteration. You shouldn't, because you are not changing the length of anything while iterating though the loop.

Next, you check whether the number hasn't been found with:

```
if (i == len_n) ...
```

That doesn't work, because you update the frequency in the first loop, but don't terminate the loop; your condition will always be true. You can fix this by breaking out of the loop explicitly with `break` when you have found the number. (Better yet, make the look-up and frequency update a function whose return value indicates whether the element was found and add the elemen if it wasn't.)

When you append the new element:

```
if (i == len_n) {
  a_num[i+1] = inputnum;
  a_freq[i+1] = 1;
}
```

you should, of course, increment the length of the array you append to. In general, appending an item to an array looks like this:

```
array[len++] = item;
```

Recall that the first index is zero and that the actual length is one beyond the valid indices.

There are other points:

- When you add an element, you should make sure that you don't overflow the array. The dimension of 1000 is generous, but not infinite.
- In your function `ar_max`, you iterate over all 1000 elements of the array. You have initialised the arrays to zero, so the maximum will still be right, but it is better to pass the array size to the function, too, so that you can iterate over only the actual items.
- If your function `ar_max` returned an index instead of a value, you could access both array with that index and you wouldn't need the last loop over `j`, because `j` is just that index.
- If you have two parallel arrays, it is a good idea to create a struct that hold the item and frequency and always keeps them together. That simplifies the code, because you don't have to keep anything in sync. Such a data layout also lends itself to sorting and filtering other common operations.

Here's a version that implements the fixes described above. It also uses a function to look up an element by value and makes `ar_max` return an array index instead of a value.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAX 1000

int getint()
{
    int x;

    if (scanf("%d", &x) < 1) return EOF;
    return x;
}

int ar_max(const int a[], int len)
{
    if (len == 0) return -1;

    int max_so_far = a[0];
    int max_index = 0;

    for (int i = 1; i < len; i++) {
        if (a[i] > max_so_far) {
            max_so_far = a[i];
            max_index = i;
        }
    }

    return max_index;
}

int ar_find(const int a[], int len, int which)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        if (a[i] == which) return i;
    }

    return -1;
}

int main()
{
    int inputnum = getint();

    int a_num[MAX] = { };       // distinct numbers seen  
    int a_freq[MAX] = { };      // frequencies of the distinct numbers
    int len = 0;                // actual length of both arrays

    while (inputnum != EOF) {
        int i = ar_find(a_num, len, inputnum);

        if (i < 0) {            // append new item
            if (len >= MAX) {
                fprintf(stderr, "Array size %d exceeded\n", MAX);
                exit(1);
            }
            a_num[len] = inputnum;
            a_freq[len] = 1;
            len++;
        } else {                // increment existing item
            a_freq[i]++;
        }

        inputnum = getint();
    }

    int imax = ar_max(a_freq, len);
    if (imax >= 0) {
        printf("%d (%d times)\n", a_num[imax], a_freq[imax]);
    } else {
        puts("Empty input.");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int main() 
{
  // array containing the distinct numbers seen
  int a_num[1000] = {0};
  // array containing the frequencies of the distinct numbers seen
  int a_freq[1000] = {0};
  int len_n = 0;
  int i = 0, j = 0;

  // Read first entry
  int inputnum = getint();
  if (EOF == inputnum)
  {
      printf("No valid number input given\n");
      return -1;
  }

  // Make first entry in a_num and a_freq
  a_num[0] = inputnum;
  a_freq[0] = 1;
  // Update len_n to 1
  len_n = 1;

  // Get new entry from user and update number array and frequency array
  inputnum = getint();
  while (inputnum != EOF) 
  {
      // update the frequency of inputnum if it's already been seen
      for (i = 0; i < len_n; i++) 
      {
          if (a_num[i] == inputnum) 
          {
              a_freq[i] = a_freq[i] + 1;
              break;
          }
      }

      // add inputnum into the array if it hasn't already been seen
      if (i == len_n) 
      {
          a_num[i] = inputnum;
          a_freq[i] = 1;

          // Update len_n
          len_n++;
      }

      // Check if we have already reached 1000
      if (1000 == len_n)
      {
          printf("Reached 1000 entry read\n");
          break;
      }

      // Next entry
      inputnum = getint();
  }

  // print the number with the highest frequency
  int max_freq = ar_max(a_freq);
  for (j = 0; j < len_n; j++) 
  {
      if (a_freq[j] == max_freq) 
      {
          printf("%d\n", a_num[j]);
          break;
      }
  }
}
```

NOTE:
1. #define MAX_SIZE 1000 can be used since hardcoded value 1000 is used repeatedly in code. This will help when you have use new size (say 1500) and you need to change only the #define MAX_SIZE 1500, other code remains unchanged.
2. ar_max() function can be modified to give array index where max occurs to avoid the for loop in main to find the array index. e.g.

```
int ar_max(int a[])
{
  int index = 0;
  int max_so_far = a[0];
  for (int i = 1; i < 1000; i++) {
    if (a[i] > max_so_far) {
      max_so_far = a[i];
      index = i;
    }
  }
  return index;
}
```

In main():

```
printf("%d\n", a_num[ar_max(a_freq)]);
```